# Combine two dataframes of dfiferent size into one

Tags: pandas, merge, append, concatenation, union

I am looking to append two dataframes together that are different in size.  I have tried append, merge, concat - I know I am close but missing something fairly easy.  I am new to Python learning on my own.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['lj', 22.72, 37, 9.8], ['nc', 13.24, 30.9, 4.4],['bm', 13.77, 26.3, 9.3], ['jl', 12, 25.9, 7.2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Name', 'Proj', 'Ceil', 'Floor'])
print(df)

data2 = [['0', 50, 55, 25, 20], ['1', 49, 54, 24, 19], ['2', 33, 2, 27, 18], ['3', 14, 60, 17, 35], ['4', 45, 40, 48, 10], ['5', 10, 15, 35, 30], ['6', 57, 75, 27, 27], ['7', 22, 17, 18, 11], ['8', 3, 6, 26, 36], ['9', 12, 32, 5, 3]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['sim_id', 'lj', 'nc', 'bn', 'jl'])
print(df2)
```

|  | Name | Proj | Ceil | Floor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 |

|  | sim_id | lj | nc | bn | jl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 50 | 55 | 25 | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 49 | 54 | 24 | 19 |
| 2 | 2 | 33 | 2 | 27 | 18 |
| 3 | 3 | 14 | 60 | 17 | 35 |
| 4 | 4 | 45 | 40 | 48 | 10 |
| 5 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 35 | 30 |
| 6 | 6 | 57 | 75 | 27 | 27 |
| 7 | 7 | 22 | 17 | 18 | 11 |
| 8 | 8 | 3 | 6 | 26 | 36 |
| 9 | 9 | 12 | 32 | 5 | 3 |

***Desired Output***

|  | Name | Proj | Ceil | Floor | sim_id | proj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 0 | 50 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 1 | 49 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 2 | 33 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 3 | 14 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 4 | 45 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 5 | 10 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 6 | 57 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 7 | 22 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 8 | 3 |
| 0 | lj | 22.72 | 37 | 9.8 | 9 | 12 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 0 | 55 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 1 | 54 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 3 | 60 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 4 | 40 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 5 | 15 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 6 | 75 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 7 | 17 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 8 | 6 |
| 1 | nc | 13.24 | 30.9 | 4.4 | 9 | 32 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 0 | 25 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 1 | 24 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 2 | 27 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 3 | 17 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 4 | 48 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 5 | 35 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 6 | 27 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 7 | 18 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 8 | 26 |
| 2 | bm | 13.77 | 26.3 | 9.3 | 9 | 5 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 0 | 20 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 1 | 19 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 2 | 18 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 3 | 35 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 4 | 10 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 5 | 30 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 6 | 27 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 7 | 11 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 8 | 36 |
| 3 | jl | 12 | 25.9 | 7.2 | 9 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`. But you would need a common column to join both the dataframes. Since you don't have any common column, one way is to create a temporary column just for join and then drop it. Something like below.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['lj', 22.72, 37, 9.8], ['nc', 13.24, 30.9, 4.4],['bm', 13.77, 26.3, 9.3], ['jl', 12, 25.9, 7.2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Name', 'Proj', 'Ceil', 'Floor'])
print(df)

data2 = [['0', 50, 55, 25, 20], ['1', 49, 54, 24, 19], ['2', 33, 2, 27, 18], ['3', 14, 60, 17, 35], ['4', 45, 40, 48, 10], ['5', 10, 15, 35, 30], ['6', 57, 75, 27, 27], ['7', 22, 17, 18, 11], ['8', 3, 6, 26, 36], ['9', 12, 32, 5, 3]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['sim_id', 'lj', 'nc', 'bn', 'jl'])
print(df2)
#add the below lines
df['temp']=1
df2['temp']=1
df3 = pd.merge(df,df2, on=['temp'])
df3 = df3.drop('temp', axis=1)
print(df3)
```

Comment: You can also try a one liner using `assign` `df.assign(temp=1).merge(df2.assign(temp=1), on='temp').drop('temp', 1)` ;)

Comment: Yes. That looks more simpler :) @ShubhamSharma

Comment: Follow up question for Arun.  The merge worked but it results in the values being merged across the columns, if I wanted to do the equivalent of an index match to only return the value for the given 'Name' how would I go about doing that.  I have tried lookup but get length of row and columns must be equal.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want `df.loc`. Use `df3.loc[df3['Name']=='nc']` or simply `df3[df3['Name']=='nc']` to return rows that have `Name` as `nc` @Ian